# Vue - refresh value of data i'm passing to Component

Tags: vue.js

I'm passing a variable from a parent to a child component like so:

**parent Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <childComponent :lastPrice="lastPrice"></childComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  props:{

    lastPrice:{
      type:Number,
      default: 0
    }

  
  },

  mounted() {

    this.fetchLastPrice()
  },

  methods: {
    fetchLastPrice(){
      fetch('MY-API')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.lastPrice = data['lastPrice']
      })
    }
  }

}

</script>
```

And then i have the **childComponent**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Last price: {{lastPrice}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
     
<script>

export default {

  props:{

    lastPrice:{
      type:Number,
      default: '',
    }

  },

  mounted() {
    console.log('Mounted')
  },

  methods: {
    ...
  }
}

</script>
```

In the parent component, i define `lastPrice` and i pass it to the child component. Then i change the value of `lastPrice` in the parent component. The problem with my code is that, in the child component, the value of `lastPrice` is always `0`. Is there any way i can make it reactive? I would like to avoid using Vuex as it's overkill for this task, if possible. Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Parent component you defined lastPrice as props, so you can not mutate it to pass it to you Child component.

Here a sandBox with a functional example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-faraday-50liu?file=/src/components/Parent.vue

Answer (score 1):

In the parent component you defined a prop instead of some data.

Try this instead in the parent component:

```js
data() {
  return { lastPrice: 0 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. But how do i set a new value to lastPrice? Do i need to do this.lastPrice = 120 for example?